# How to iterate for loop in vlookup?

Tags: excel, vba

I have to take a column's value and map it to another column in another workbook using vLookup. The problem here is that it takes only one value to iterate through the loop even if it's random then it rejects the next upcoming value. This is giving me subscript out of range error. Following is my code-

```
Sub S1_Outage()

Dim rLookRange As Range
Dim Node_id As Long
Dim Wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

'Removing Duplicates
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=3, Header:=xlYes


'Insert column
Range("D1").EntireColumn.Insert
Range("D1").Value = "Zone"
LastRow = Sheets("10Hrs 4G S1 Outage (1)").Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

    Node_id = Sheets("10Hrs 4G S1 Outage (1)").Cells(i, "C").Value
    Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Khushi\Desktop\CXX_March.xlsx")
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
         Set rLookRange = ws.Range("A:C")
         
      Workbooks("10Hrs 4G S1 Outage (1).xlsm").Sheets("10Hrs 4G S1 Outage (1)").Cells(i, "D").Value  = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Node_id, rLookRange, 3, False)
    
 Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Why is the Workbook Open inside of the Loop?  What line is generating the error?

Comment: This is the another workbook from which we have to map values from column A to C and it must be applied to each cell in 1st workbook that's why it's in a loop. This A to C range is for vlookup.

Comment: But it is always the same file.  You only need to open it once outside of the loop.  The range rLookRange will remain available throughout the life of the sub.  And which line generates the error?

Comment: Okay, Thanks I got it I will make the corrections. This is the line which generates the error only when run for more than 1 time in loop. It runs okay for the 1st time. `Node_id = Sheets("10Hrs 4G S1 Outage (1)").Cells(i, "C").Value`

Comment: It is the activation of the second sheet.  When that sheet is activated, it no longer "looks" and the first workbook, and therefore no longer finds a worksheet by that name.  Create variables to define these worksheets and remove the activate statement.
```dim ws1 as worksheet```
```set ws1 = sheets("10Hrs....")```

Comment: ```dim ws2 as worksheet```
 ```set ws2 = Wb1.sheet(1)``` You may need to use the correct worksheet name instead of the index for that one.

Comment: Also add a ```Wb1.close``` after the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim rLookRange As Range
Dim Node_id As Long
Dim Wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

'Removing Duplicates
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=3, Header:=xlYes


'Insert column
Range("D1").EntireColumn.Insert
Range("D1").Value = "Zone"
Set ws = Sheets("10Hrs 4G S1 Outage (1)")
LastRow = ws.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row
    Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Khushi\Desktop\CXX_March.xlsx")
    Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
    Set rLookRange = ws1.Range("A:C")
    ws.Activate  ' optional
    
For i = 2 To LastRow

    Node_id = ws.Cells(i, "C").Value
         
      ws.Cells(i, "D").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Node_id, rLookRange, 3, False)
    
 Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It works... Thank you so much for your valuable response I've been finding the solution since 2 weeks n here it is :)